# how to save while editing in /lightdm.conf

Tags: lightdm

Hi I tried disabling guest account by editing lightdm and a bug sends me to it showing low graphics. I went I to termin and undid the change I made in /lightdm.conf but don't know how to save tbe change and exit. How do I? I'm pretty sure u doing the added code is all that needs tk be done, I didn't do anything else to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which terminal-based editor you used

- for `nano`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and confirm the filename to overwrite, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit
- for `vim`, type <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit *insert mode*, then `:wq` to write and quit